# Convert a two array object into a one array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, each

I have an object with the following values:

```
"Obj": {
    "value1": [],
    "value2": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "4"
    ]
}
```

If I check my obj I can see that its size is equal to 2. That makes sense, of course, 'cause I have two arrays here. But the thing is, I need it to have one array only. By that I mean: I want to convert those 2 arrays into one array.

Have been trying for a while with a few methods. None of them had the expected behavior.

For example:

```
var arr = [];
arr = [sRows.value1, sRows.value2]
```

Or:

```
$.each(sRows, function(k,v){
    result[i] = v;
})
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure how you want to combine your arrays (you don't say), but my glass ball is telling me [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) may be what you are searching for.

Comment: Are there always just going to be 2 values? Are those values always going to be arrays? How do you want the conversion to be (value1 followed by value2, vice versa, no duplicates....)?

Comment: Always two arrays, not specific order. And yes, no duplicates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two arrays in JavaScript and de-duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items)

Comment: In your example above, what is the correctly value you expect as a size for your `Obj` ? 5? or 4?

Comment: I expect a length of "1".

Comment: Given the information you gave us, both mine and Jonas' answer will work. Are you sure your expectation of what an empty array or empty object look like match reality?

Answer (score 0):

How about [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) ?

```
let new_array = sRows.value1.concat(sRows.value2);
```

> The concat() method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method
>   does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.

Comment: Can't use concat 'cause the value of the first array is an empty object.

Comment: That shouldn't matter: https://repl.it/@calebjay/BlueNeatQuark

Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Sure. When I do it like this, the resulting value's:  (4) ["1", "2", "3", "4"]. So it creates 4 different elements with every value of "value1" and ignores "value2". Not working as expected, then.

Comment: In your example, value1 is an empty array. The empty array has nothing to copy, so nothing is copied. How does this differ from your expectation? (I'm assuming in your comment you accidentally wrote value2 when you meant value1)

Comment: Yes, sorry. That's what I meant. The actual problem's what I pointed out first: "It's returning an array.length of "4".

Comment: It is correct. Try this: do `console.log(sRows.value1.length + sRows.value2.length)` and see if that matches your expectations.

Comment: Even better: `console.log((sRows.value1.length + sRows.value2.length) === sRows.value1.concat(sRows.value2).length)`

Comment: This is also an option   sRows.value1.push( ...sRows.value2 ) or sRows.value2.unshift( ...sRows.value1 ) to make it for opposit

Answer (score 0):

This function will convert your object into a single array:

```
function convertArraysToArray(obj) {
    var output = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
            for (var index = 0; index < obj[key].length; index++) {
                output.push(obj[key][index]);
            }
        } else {
            output.push(obj[key]);
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

If you intend to make it a single element of an object, you can achieve that easily as well.